# Update to quotedetail entity does it's changes only after another update call

Tags: sdk, dynamics-crm

I am currently wrestling some weird issue.

When my code executes an update call (be it by plugin of forms script due to an onChange event), it only updates the field with the value of a previous update call. I can see it gets the correct value right before the execution, but what is stored in CRM is the wrong one.

i.e.

When I expect 1, I get whatever was before.

Then, when I want to set it to 2, It becomes the 1 I wanted in the line above.

then for 4, it's 2,

for 8 it's 4,

for 1 again it becomes 8,

etc...

I hadn't this issue at first, but it suddenly cropped up after rearranging code and events.

[The desired update value and what is stored in CRM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxfCs.png)

[After sending the update request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xr0ZR.png)

Too bad I lack rep, because I have two more screenshots, but I hope I made it clear anyways.

This piece is overdue and I assume it to be a bug in Dynamics CRM.

Comment: Please share some code of your plugin. Does your plugin class have fields?

Comment: What is your version of CRM? How do you observe the value stored in CRM?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. it was a problem with the code being repeated again with older values, a remainder that came up by taking over an existing project and not knowing what everything does.

Thanks for trying to help me figure it out.